# Android Получение разной даты в миллисекундах

Tags: java, android, дата

У меня назрел такой вопрос, как получить нужное время по дате в миллисекундах. Время которое сейчас можно получить просто введя System.currentTimeMillis().
А как получить время в миллисекундах, скажем на начало сегодняшнего дня или начало текущей недели, ну и все прочие, начало месяца, начало квартала и  начало года. Можно конечно, расчеты всякие делать, но это не гуд, я предполагаю что можно использовать календарь, но я в нём не силён, вообще не силён.

Comment: всё правильно. через календарь

Comment: А в чём проблема? Погуглите календарь. Там всё очень просто

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Маленькая cправка

`Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` возвращает объект `Date`

Метод `.getTime()` объекта `Date` вернёт количество миллисекунд с начала эпохи в формате `long`

Конструктор `Date(int year, int month, int day)` создаст объект `Date` и установит время 00:00

Существуют и другие конструкторы `Date`
Чтобы увидеть доступные конструкторы в IDE Android Studio/IntelliJ IDEA нажмите комбинации клавиш CTRL+P

Пример: введите `new Date()` и нажмите комбинацию CTRL+P. IDE покажет вам все существующие конструкторы

---

Теперь перейдём к решению:

```
    //Первый месяц в Date считается 0 (Январь), последний - 11(Декабрь)
    final int firstMonth = 0;
    final int firstDay = 1;
    //Давайте получим 01.01.ТЕКУЩИЙ_ГОД в миллисекундах.
    //Для этого создадим объект Date с датой 01.01.ТЕКУЩИЙ_ГОД
    Date current_year = new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getYear(), firstMonth, firstDay);
    //получим количество секунд на 01.01.ТЕКУЩИЙ_ГОД 00:00:00 UTC
    long current_year_in_milliseconds = current_year.getTime();
```

Для удобства в работе оберните этот код в метод

```
public static long getCurrentYearTimeInMilliseconds(){
  //код
}
```

и используйте где необходимо. По аналогии можете создать другие методы.

P.S. Не забудьте импортировать `import java.util.Date;`

Comment: О_о вот это очень полезный ответ